# How to assign the user input value to a variable?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code

```
{
   var selectBox = document.getElementById("shapes");
   var selectedShape = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].text;
   var tempSection = document.getElementById("emptySection");  
   var trianglelegend = document.getElementById("legend");
   trianglelegend.innerHTML = "Triangle Measurements"; 
   var baseLabel = createLabel("baseId", "Enter the base  here:");
   var heightLabel = createLabel("heightId", "Enter the height here:");
   var baseInput = createInput("baseId", "number"); 
   var heightInput = createInput("heightId", "number");
   tempSection.append(baseLabel,heightLabel,baseInput,heightInput); 
   document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", triangleCalculations); 
}
```

I am trying to the values the user entered in and use them in the function here below

```
{
    var height = document.getElementById("heightId");
    var base = document.getElementById("baseId");
    height = parseInt(height); 
    base = parseInt(base);
    var areaBox = document.getElementById("Area");
    areaBox.value = String(1/2 * base * height);
}
```

Where do I declare base and height variables to get the item the user enters in?

Comment: `var height = document.getElementById("heightId").value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) returns an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). You can think of an element as a normal object with properties and methods that you can use.

Depending on the tag that has the `id="heightId"`, you may be able to access its value differently.

Since it's probable that your `Element` is an input, you can get the height by accessing its `value` property with `var height = document.getElementById("heightId").value`

You can find more info about different Elements and their methods/properties in the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element)

Answer (score 0):

To get value of **label** you need to write

`var el = document.getElementById('heightId'); text = (el.innerText || el.textContent);`

same with `baseId`